# Angular JS Injecting Custom Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't get angular to accept my custom service, which is in a seperate file. I know this is all over stack overflow, but I just can't tell where I'm messing up.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularApp">
<head>
  <!-- ANGULAR -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link href="styles/angularApp.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="scripts/controllers/angularApp.js"></script>
  <script src ="scripts/services/clearCodemirror.js"></script>
```

Main angular javascript file (contains my controller)

```
var myApp = angular.module("angularApp", ["ui.codemirror","ui.bootstrap", "ngSanitize", "ngRoute"]);

myApp.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "$timeout", "clearCodemirror", function($scope, $timeout, clearCodemirror){
```

Service I'm trying to inject:

```
var myApp = angular.module("angularApp");

myApp.service("clearCodemirror", function(cm){
```

Error I keep getting:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularApp&p1=Error…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A56)
```

I only included the beginnings of each file so you guys wouldn't have to wade through tons of code. Where am I screwing up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By calling angular.module("angularApp") from your 2nd file, you are recreating a angular module, and NOT getting a reference to the module that was created on the previous file.

There are a few ways to solve that. The simplest one (on my point of view) is to set your angular app to a window.VARIABLE.

```
window.myApp = angular.module("angularApp", ["ui.codemirror","ui.bootstrap", "ngSanitize", "ngRoute"]);
```

Then, from your 2nd file you can:

```
var myApp = window.myApp;

myApp.service("clearCodemirror", function(cm){
```

There are better ways to do that. However, this one you get you going. Cheers!

Comment: Still getting the same error when I do that. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are not re creating the module you are getting the existing module by var myApp = angular.module("angularApp");
 as the docs states :-
      https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

**When passed two or more arguments, a new module is created. If passed only one argument, an existing module (the name passed as the first argument to module) is retrieved.**

i tried with 1.3.14 , i didnt got any error, which version are you using:-